# How much of Heavensward can I access right off with a low level character?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I am thinking of coming back to Final Fantasy 14 and I know there is a new expansion. My character was not max level in the original game, so I know that there will be a lot of storyline/leveling/etc. I need to do before I can even access the main questline of Heavensward.

My question is ...

Is there anything I will get to have right off (new professions/crafting/jobs/etc.) with the expansion even at a low level? Or would I be just as fine resubbing now, leveling up, completing the original game, then just buying the expansion when I'm ready for the new content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only Heavensward content available before max level is the Au Ra race and the increased level cap. You can create a new character or use Fantasia on an existing character to become an Au Ra as well as level classes past 50, but other Heavensward content is locked until you complete the main story questline leading up to the expansion.

Comment: How about the new classes?

Comment: The new jobs are acquired in the new Heavensward areas and so are locked until you complete the main story questline.

Comment: Also, all new jobs /start/ at level 30 and have no base class.